# Placeholder R output

Tags: r, knitr

I want to generate several PDF pages. Each one has the same content except for a placeholder that I want to fill in from R. I don't really know how to search for this, the word placeholder may not be right...
Here's what I mean:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
This will be the header of each page, with formatted text etc.\\
Then we need a placeholder for output from R:\\
<<fakedata, echo=FALSE>>=
Names <- c("John", "Mary", "Tom")
# In reality, there is more and more complex data
for(i in 1:3)
print(Names[i])
@
But I only want one name here, and then the rest of the Latex code output. On the next page should be all the rest again, with the second name, and so on.\\[\baselineskip]
Then there is more stuff filling the page, optimally also including the i-th output of other stuff. This also includes a table and form fields (thus LATEX code), so I can not just use the R commands paste and cat...\\
Thanks for any ideas!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Create a file called `doc.Rnw.0`, say, containing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
This will be the header of each page, with formatted text etc.\\
Then we need a placeholder for output from R:\\
<<fakedata, echo=FALSE>>=
# In reality, there is more and more complex data
$Name
@
But I only want one name here, and then the rest of the Latex code output. On the next 
page should be all the rest again, with the second name, and so on.\\[\baselineskip]
Then there is more stuff filling the page, optimally also including the i-th output of other 
stuff. This also includes a table and form fields (thus LATEX code), so I can not just use 
the R commands paste and cat...\\
Thanks for any ideas!
\end{document}
```

and then in R run this:

```
library(gsubfn)

doc <- readLines("doc.Rnw.0")
doc <- paste(doc, collapse = "\n")
Names <- c("John", "Mary", "Tom")

for(i in 1:3) {
    Name <- Names[i]
    fn$cat(doc, file = paste("doc", Name, "Rnw", sep = "."))
}
```

This will create a separate file for each of the values of `Name`.

The above assumes we do not use dollar or backquote in the file other than for text substitution.
If that does not hold then replace `$Name` in `doc.Rnw.0` with, say, `@Name` and and replace the `fn$cat(...)` statement with:

```
pat <- pattern <- "@([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:].]*)
doc2 <- gsubfn(pat,, doc)
cat(doc2, file = paste("doc", Name, "Rnw", sep = "."))
```

Note that we may have many substitutions.  For example, if we have `Name` and `Address` just define both in R and then use `$Name` and `$Address` (or `@Name` and `@Address` if we use the alternative) at the appropriate points in the `doc.Rnw.0` file.

**2)** The `brew` package would be another approach.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with markdown-flavoured `brew` in my [pander package](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#brew-to-pandoc) that handles such loops internally (based on `brew` with `<% ... %>` tags. Quick demo:

Create a file (like `demo.pander`) with the following content:

```
# This will be the header of each page, with formatted text etc.

Then we need a placeholder for output from R.

<% 
Names <- c("John", "Mary", "Tom")
for(i in 1:3) {
%>

This sentence will be printed for each `Names` and the R code run: <%= Names[i] %>

<% } %>

But I only want one name here, and then the rest of the Latex code output. On the next page should be all the rest again, with the second name, and so on.
```

Please note that I have used `<% ... %>` tags for running R code (like a loop), but `<%= ... %>` for printing results. That latter also applies `pander` on the returning R object, so that would return in Pandoc's markdown.

Then simply call `Pandoc.brew`:

```
> library(pander)
> Pandoc.brew('demo.pander')
# This will be the header of each page, with formatted text etc.

Then we need a placeholder for output from R.

This sentence will be printed for each `Names` and the R code run: John

This sentence will be printed for each `Names` and the R code run: Mary

This sentence will be printed for each `Names` and the R code run: Tom

But I only want one name here, and then the rest of the Latex code output. On the next page should be all the rest again, with the second name, and so on.
```

Now you have a markdown file that can be convert to `tex`, `pdf` or any other format.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the two replys so far - quite nice ideas. When I woke up, I had another solution I also wanted to try. No packages, pure R code that then creates a single tex-document that creates a single pdf. In my case, I want one PDF with many (almost) identical pages that I can print just like that. 
Here's the code:

```
# Create Latex File with Placeholder for R output
# Berry Boessenkool, Jan 2014, berry-b@gmx.de
# Remember to replace Latex's Backslash with two \\

# What file to create:
outputfile <- "Test3.tex"

# Document preamble:
cat("\\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\\begin{document}\n", file=outputfile)

# R results for placeholder:
Names <- c("John", "Mary", "Tom")

# Main content, to be repeated on each page:
for(i in 1:3)
{
cat(paste(
"This will be the header of each page, with formatted text etc.\\\\
Then we need a placeholder for output from R:\\\\",
Names[i],
"\\\\and then the rest of the Latex code output. \\\\[\\baselineskip]
On the next page should be all the rest again, with the second name, and so on.\n
\\newpage\n"
, sep="\n"), file=outputfile, append=T)
}

# End of document:
cat("\n\\end{document}", file=outputfile, append=T)
```

Most likely, the invariable page content could also be read in from a separate file. And the annoying \\ could be avoided...
Thanks for your ideas though, I might need them later on!

Comment: advice: don't do this. Neat packages such as brew, pander, whisker, etc. have been carefully written for this purpose, and they'll save you a lot of head-scratching, obscure code and dangerous escapes.